# How to I return a list of all the elements of the self model in flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I was following the [flask mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database), and I created my own model in `models.py`

```
class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Item {}>'.format(self.body)

    def all_items(self): #some code
```

So now I have pushed some `Items` in this the table, and I want to write a function that returns all the entries in this table. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all items you can just do the following:

```
all_items = Item.query.all()
```

Wrapping this in a function doesn't seem necessary, but its up to you and your needs.